# VMware Workstation Playerで仮想マシンのBIOS設定画面が表示できない

Tags: vmware

VVMware Workstation Playerで仮想化機能を有効にするために仮想マシンのBIOS設定を開きたいのですが、Boot Manager画面しか表示されません。

以下を試してみましたが、Boot Manager画面しか表示されませんでした。

- 設定の回復項目から再起動後、トラブルシューティングの詳細からUEFIファームウェアの設定で再起動
- vmxファイルに「bios.bootDelay = "5000"」を記載し、ESCやDeleteやF1~F12キーを連打
- vmxファイルに「bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"」を記載し起動

環境は以下になります。

VMソフトウェア: VMware Workstation 16 Player
ホストOS: Windows10
ゲストOS: Windows11

PCの起動の仕組み等はいまいち理解していません。

Comment: vmx ファイルを編集するのではなく、GUI からゲスト OS の設定を変更できませんか？ https://docs.vmware.com/jp/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-3140DF1F-A105-4EED-B9E8-D99B3D3F0447.html

Comment: 仮想マシンの BIOS ではなく、ホストの BIOS / UEFI じゃなくて？

Comment: ありがとうございます。GUIから設定変更ができました。

Answer (score 1):

VMware Workstation 16 Playerの仮想マシン設定のプロセッサから、[Intel VT-x/EPT または AMD-V/RVI を仮想化] の項目で設定はできました。
ただ、VM起動時に「Intel VT-x/EPTはこのプラットフォームではサポートされていません。」となり、VMが起動できない状態になりました。
本来の目的である仮想マシン上でWSLを使えるようにするにはVMよりHyper-Vを使った方が簡単に実現できそうだったので、Hyper-Vを使って仮想マシンを作ってみると、仮想マシン上でWSLが起動できるようになりました。